# Problem in getting refernce to ajax extender control

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

I am having problem in getting reference of Ajax control extender using $find() or $get or document.getElelmentById() functions in java script

Can any one tell me how can to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

$get('<%=extenderId.ClientID %>') or document.getElementById('<%=extenderId.ClientID %>')

Answer (score 2):

If you speak about ASP.NET AjaxControlToolkit extenders, actually they do not render any control in the page, but can be accessed as special members of the control they extend.
For example, if a `TextBox` has a `CalendarExtender`, it can be accessed from javascript code with:

```
document.getElementById('myTextBoxClientID').CalendarBehavior
```